# Clojure mutimethods for dispatch by type

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop, multimethod

I implemented fast power algorithm in clojure:

```
(defn fast-pow [a n]
  (cond (zero? n) 1
    (even? n) (letfn [(square [x] (*' x x))]
                (square (fast-pow a (/ n 2))))
    :else (*' a (fast-pow a (dec' n)))))
```

And now I want to play with type hints and java interop. I want to do this because of better understanding all this "java stuff" in a clojure. It's looks like their are pretty easy, but in fact there is a lot of hidden obstacle. So, I wrote:

```
(defn ^java.math.BigInteger fast-pow 
  ([^java.lang.Long a ^java.lang.Long n]
   (fast-pow (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf a) (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf n)))
  ([^java.math.BigInteger a ^java.math.BigInteger n]
   (cond (zero? n) java.math.BigInteger/ONE
         (even? n) (letfn [(square [x] (.multiply x x))]
                    (square (fast-pow a (.divide n (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf 2)))))
         :else (.multiply a (fast-pow a (.subtract n BigInteger/ONE))))))
```

Of course it's not even compiled, because of wrong arity problem. So I google how to dispatch by type in clojure and found `multimethods`. In fact at this point I was vary naive and excited, I never tried `multimethods` before, so, I wrote something alike:

```
(derive java.math.BigInteger ::biginteger)
(derive java.lang.Long ::long)
(defmulti fast-pow (fn [a n] [(class a) (class n)]))

(defmethod fast-pow [::biginteger ::biginteger] [a n]
  (cond (zero? n) java.math.BigInteger/ONE
        (even? n) (letfn [(square [x] (.multiply x x))]
                    (square (fast-pow a (.divide n (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf 2)))))
        :else (.multiply a (fast-pow a (.subtract n BigInteger/ONE)))))
(defmethod fast-pow [::long ::long] [a n] 
  (fast-pow 
   (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf a) 
   (java.math.BigInteger/valueOf n)))
```

Things are going a bit complicated. That works fine, but I wonder is there a more clean way to such thing as just overload by type. I didn't get why in clojure I cannot do that even if in Java I can.

PS: Of course I can "hide" logic based on `java.math.BigInteger` inside an nested function, and call it from outer function `fast-pow`, but in fact - it's not interesting for me, I pretty sure, this issue could be solved by using `multimethods`. If I'm wrong or missing something - please explain it to me.. ;)

Comment: Just some style hints: extract the `square` function to the outside, it's no use to define it locally via `letfn` on every recursion step. Also, take a look at `recur` (and probably `loop`) and move the recursive call to a tail-call position -- the way you're doing the recursion is likely to blow the stack quite soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dispatch based on the type of more than one argument then multimethods are the appropriate tool. keep in mind that this is already built into all the promoting math functions such as +' and *'.

```
user> (+' 2N 3)
5N
```

You cannot, in clojure, use type hints to accomplish this type of overloading/dispatch (and this was done on purpose). If you are only dispatching based on the first argument you should use [protocols](http://clojure.org/reference/protocols) because they are *much* faster.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but why it's so complicated? I mean, Isn't dispatch by type already implemented in JVM? Is it because evey function in clojure looks lika an class for JVM?

Comment: I can't really speak to the personal motivation of why, though the language was designed this way. Multimethods offer a fully generic dispatch method that covers this and every other type of dispatch that can be expressed at invocation time. And protocols offer dispatch by the first arguement which is the vast vast majority cases. So I can only assume that dispatch by type of the second argument was not seen as important enough to warrant a third dispatch type (and protocols where added later, originally Clojure only had multimethods). If you want you can build this feature using macros